# Loading images from resources taking more time in android

Tags: android, loading, android-drawable

In my android application i am displaying nearly 100 images in the home screen using listviews. I kept all the images in the "drawable" folder only, but its taking nearly 8 to 14 seconds to load the home screen.

I using following code.

```
private class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView product_image;
    }

final ViewHolder holder;

holder.product_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId));
```

I checked a lot but i did't find any better way to load the images from drawable folder.

Can any one help me ?

thanks.

Comment: You can use image cache library. Please find https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I tried Android-Universal-Image-Loader library but its only loading images from rest not from drawable folder. If it will works for that also, can post the answer how to do that.

Comment: Use AQuery Lib: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
holder.product_image.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

this way avoid using BitmapFactory.
So maybe this way more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use an AsyncTask to load the images.
2. While loading images through `decodeResource()` you should `BitmapFactory.Options` so that the entire bitmap is not loaded in the memory but only the size you want to display.